# My SQL ADDDATE FUNCTION is not working in CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table in which there is `OPENDATE` field. The default value for which should be 30 days earlier to system date.

```
CREATE TABLE bugs (
    ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    TITLE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    SEVERITY INT NOT NULL check(SEVERITY>0 && SEVIRITY<5),
    OPENDATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT ADDDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,-30),
    CLOSEDATE DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

1. This gives error at `ADDDATE` function. Can I not use functions at the table creation time? If no, what's the solution, and If yes, why this is not working?
2. I also noticed that the identifier `CURRENT_DATE` is not recognized. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible:

> The `DEFAULT` value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, **the default value must be a constant**; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE`. The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns.
>
> ***source:*** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html

You have to control the default value of the column on the application itself. After creation and initializing the table with some data, you can `UPDATE` the column with such data or use a trigger (on insert) to set the value immediately after creating the row.

Comment: @sebastianbrosch- Should the line changed work? OPENDATE date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE

Comment: @sebastianbrosch- sorry, modified as the datatype as DATATIME and identifier as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and got this working.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I not use functions at the table creation time?

That's correct. You cannot use functions in table definitions.

You can define a column in a table like this:

```
 insertdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

MySQL only recognizes `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in this context, not `CURRENT_DATE` or any other symbol or function.

Then, you can do something like this in a query.

```
 SELECT ... insertdate - INTERVAL 30 DAY opendate
```

Or, you could even define an opendate column like this:

```
 opendate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL
```

then use a query pattern like this:

```
SELECT ... WHEN opendate IS NULL 
               THEN insertdate - INTERVAL 30 DAY
               ELSE opendate END  opendate
```

That will give back your `opendate` column if you set it, otherwise the computed opendate value. But you need to work out your business rules around this quite carefully.

Comment: If I change the line as... OPENDATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, --this works where as the line... OPENDATE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE --not working. according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html CURRENT_DATE identifier should be valid...